# Change Configuration of a Project by Reading Command_Line in C

Tags: c, command-line, configuration, macros

it might be a silly question but may I ask how can I change my project configuration in C by reading the command line?

For example, I have my C project composing with a few different files. And my `main()` which parses the command line is in `a.c`. The configuration, for example, how many threads are used named `num_thread`, default defined as a macro and is able to change in the compilation with cmakelist, is in `b.c`. While they are in different folders. But the header file of `b`, `b.h` is visible by `a.c`.

May I point out certain things that are worth noticing?

- First, the function that reads and parse the command-line, namely `main()`, is in a different file where the macro-definition (`num_threads`) situates and be used.
- Second, I could save those values read from the command-line and treat them as arguments(parameters) when I call the function that uses those macro-definition (`num_threads`). If I have that specific new value, I then replace those macros. This is workable in some simple projects. But I am so sorry to say that my project is too big and there are many layers for me to pass that single argument. So this method is not workable here.
- Third, my project involves multiple threads, so global variables should not be used at all. Because global variables are not safe in a multi-thread project.
- Fourth, I have thought a solution that I define a `static variable` in `b.c`, and have a `getter()` and `setter()`. Whenever I read a newly-defined config in `main()`, I call `setter()` to set that `static`. And whenever I use that variable, I call `getter()` to see if I have a newly read variable or not. But I don't think this method is elegant, as that `static` is kinda a global variable, even to `b.c` itself.

So, is there any way of changing such a configuration by reading command_line args? I know that change macro definition in the run time is no workable. Because the macro is processed by the preprocessor and finished in the compilation. But is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not want to encourage you to use global variables, but your comment "global variables are not safe in a multi-thread project" is incorrect. If you set the global variables before creating threads, and afterwards the threads only read the global variable, then that is thread-safe. Alternatively, if the global variable will be read/modified by multiple threads, then you can use, say, a mutex variable to make such access safe.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale, thanks for your explanation. It is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally four types of "config":

1. Compile-time configuration, the default values that are set by initializing variables in the code to fixed compile-time constants.

   Like your initialization of `num_threads` by using a macro.
2. Configuration read from a file. Not all programs need this. The configuration read from a file overrides the compile-time configuration.

   In your case it could be that you read a number from some file, then assign that number to `num_threads`.
3. Command-line arguments. This is what you're wondering about.

   For your case you need to find out the argument corresponding to `num_threads`, and assign the value to the variable.
4. Run-time configuration. Maybe not applicable in your case, but there might be events happening at run-time that causes some configuration values to be changed. Again it's a simple assignment.

The order for configuration is as shown in the list, each increasing lever have increasing priority. And this priority is kind of built-in into the system outlined above, as later configuration methods assign or reassign to the variables and thus overriding the previous value.

---

For a very simple example, lets say you only have compile-time and argument configuration options. Then that could be something like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_NUM_THREADS 4

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned num_threads = DEFAULT_NUM_THREADS;  // The compile-time configuration

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        // Have one argument, this is the new number of threads
        num_threads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);  // Argument configuration
    }

    // Use num_threads here...
}
```

If there's no argument passed to the program, the `num_thread` variable will retain its default compile-time "configuration" value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed explanation, especially for explaining the part of the config. Distinguish them are so much helpful, thanks! However, may I ask you how can I change those newly defined argument configurations, that the `main()` who reading those configurations, is not the same file as those macro definitions? How can I pass those newly defined values to that file. Thanks!

Comment: @Hongwei-W If I understand you correctly, you want to make the variable `num_threads` *global*? That is, you want to define it outside of any function. You can of course do that as well, just the same way shown in my example (but outside the `main` function then of course). To use this variable in other source file you need to add a *declaration* of the variable: `extern unsigned num_threads;` Then those other source files can use the variable normally.

Comment: @Hongwei-W By the way, you can of course define `num_threads` as a local variable and the *pass it as an argument* to the functions that need to read its value.

Comment: Well, I do not want to add any global variable. That would be the last method I want to use.  BTW, an upvote has been given.